# Are these capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, components

I've salvaged [image: these parts] from audio system. Both have two contacts. Under [image: the blue thing], on the PCB plate there was "L704" and one loop symbol, which makes thing this is an inductor - what are it's properties then? It has two red dots on top and one black on the side. [image: The black one]  has " 303j" written on it's top - I guess it's a 30nf (though meter showed nothing - it's blown) cap, but what type is it? It also has a bracket on top which indicates the negative electrode. Or the positive one.

Comment: DC resistance measurements would be useful.

Comment: Your title says they are capacitors, then the body of your question you say they are inductors....

Comment: The "J" probably just means \$\pm \:5\%\$.

Comment: Pretty weird looking parts. Soviet?

Comment: No, not Soviet. Polish. I don't know tho

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, these are **inductors**.

The "303" is very likely a **30** * 10^**3** = 30 000 nH = 30 uH inductor

The other one has two red dots and like resistors red stands for 2. This could be a 22 uH inductor or 2.2 uH.

You can check that these are inductors using a multimeter on ohms range, at DC inductors have a **low resistance**. If these were capacitors you'd measure in **infinite** DC resistance (unless the capacitor is broken).

Comment: Your base prefix seems of. A picohenry is very little and wouldn't make much sense as a unit.  And 30 nH and 2.2 nH is very tiny for audio frequencies.  I think it should be three or six orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: 30 nH has an impedance of about 37 mΩ at 200 kHz, it's negligible for usage in an audio system.

Comment: I agree.. 220 and 303 might be 22uH and 30mH

Comment: I agree, should be uH range, I updated my answer. @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 30 mH I doubt that, I have yet to see a 30 mH inductor this small.

Comment: This one is roughly same size in 33mH https://www.digikey.com/products/en/inductors-coils-chokes/fixed-inductors/71?k=&pkeyword=&pv2087=u33mH&FV=1c0003%2C142c0bf1%2Cffe00047&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=-1000011&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500  7mm diameter

Comment: Note that an electrolytic capacitor may show some conductance when the voltage is biased in the "wrong" direction.  (But generally an inductor will have much more conductance.)

Comment: The black thing has 93.7 ohms, and the blue guy is 1.5 ohms